# How to use hooks in filevault-package-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, hook, aem, acl, filevault

I'm trying to deploy ACL groups to AEM 6.5 instance. Currently recommended way is to use *filevault-package-maven-plugin* with *AcToolInstallHook*. According to documentation (https://github.com/Netcentric/accesscontroltool/blob/develop/docs/ApplyConfig.md) it should be possible. However I'm getting given error:

```
[ERROR] ValidationViolation: "jackrabbit-packagetype: Package of type 'APPLICATION' must not contain package hooks but has '{actool=biz.netcentric.cq.tools.actool.installhook.AcToolInstallHook}'!"
```

In a pom config I have package type set to application, but in documentation are examples with exactly the same config! I don't know what should I change to make it work. My plugin config in pom file:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
   <artifactId>filevault-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
     <group>com.mygroup</group>
     <name>name.myname</name>
     <packageType>application</packageType>
     <accessControlHandling>merge</accessControlHandling>
     <properties>
         <installhook.actool.class>biz.netcentric.cq.tools.actool.installhook.AcToolInstallHook</installhook.actool.class>
     </properties>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that `<packageType>application</packageType>` is the reason. Remove it and try again

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but for future reference... You should use `<packageType>container</packageType>`